# Google Analytics - viewing sessions that visited a directory

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

If I create a segment in Google Analytics to filter sessions that include a Page that starts with a directory name, will that segment show me all sessions where users visited at least one url in that directory?

[image]

I think it should, and the numbers look about right, I find GA a bit counter-intuitive at times though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that segment should work fine for what you are after.

Just keep in mind, when you apply it, if you are looking at a pageview report (for instance), other pages that were also viewed in those same sessions, will still also show in the report.